# how to stop Zune searching marketplace?

Tags: zune, music, search

I use Zune for playing music. So I use search for navigating my collection. but everytime I make some search I am wating for Zune searching marketplace. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great timing: you will not have to do anything, as right about now [browsing and buying Windows Phone apps from the Zune software will be closed down](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/04/24/two-marketplace-changes-and-how-they-affect-you.aspx). So you will just have to be patient and wait for this functionality to automatically disappear from Zune. Zune will then only be used for music management and updating the firmware of your phone.

This change will not only mean that you can then only browse and download or buy apps from your phone itself or from the [Marketplace website](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/marketplace), but you will soon have to have your phone updated to Mango (or later) if you want to continue installing and updating apps on your phone because the apps will get encrypted.

Comment: Well, this is partial solution in the end. I just restarted Zune and it got updated - old marketplace is gone. BUT new marketplace is IN - marketplace for ZuneHD apps :( But what I noticed in this update - search now doesn´t wait for marketplace results and returns music results more earlier. This is good enough for me now, despite it is not very good solution in the first place.